# How can I know that two emails are the same from two different mailboxes?

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api, office365-apps

If I send the same email to two different mailboxes, I'd like to be able to tell if these are the same email.

The problem is that the `itemId` is different for the two emails. And I can't figure a way to have a unique identifier from two identical emails.

From `Office` object in JS, I only get the `itemId` (that vary) via : `Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId` : [Documentation](https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/Office.context.mailbox.item.html#itemId)

So I've been trying to find something else from EWS Managed API via:

```
EmailMessage.Bind(service, mail.ItemId, new PropertySet(ItemSchema.Id));
```

But I can't find any useful property from `ItemSchema`. ([ItemSchema documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.itemschema_members(v=exchg.80).aspx))

How can I know that two emails are the same when they are in two different mailboxes ?

Is there a way to compare two ids ?

Comment: @MrPiao If you read the code I provided, I'm using the Office object that comes from the office365-apps context.

Comment: You're right, my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no 100% answer for this. They are actually two separate copies, so there is no actual link between them. You might be able to retrieve the RFC 822 message ID (try the `InternetMessageHeaders` property) and compare that, but you'd be assuming that nothing modified that value before you retrieved it.

Comment: What could change the `Message-ID` ?

Comment: Transport agents, any of the servers in the delivery chain (though they probably shouldn't), other apps that access the message, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add some code to @JasonJohnston answer.

**C#**

```
[HttpPost]
public List<InternetMessageHeader> GetMailHeader(MailRequest request) {
    ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
    service.Credentials = new OAuthCredentials(request.AuthenticationToken);
    service.Url = new Uri(request.EwsUrl);

    ItemId id = new ItemId(request.ItemId);
    EmailMessage email = EmailMessage.Bind(service, id, new PropertySet(ItemSchema.InternetMessageHeaders));

    if (email.InternetMessageHeaders == null)
        return null;

    return email.InternetMessageHeaders.ToList();
}
```

**JS** (using AngularJS here, but you get the idea)

```
// Request headers from server
getMailHeader()
  .then(function(response) {
    var headers = response.data;
    var messageId = findHeader("Message-ID"); // Here you get the Message-ID

    function findHeader(name) {
      for (var i in headers) {
        if (name == headers[i].Name) {
          return headers[i].Value;
        }
      }
      return null;
    }
  }, function(reason) {
    console.log(reason);
  });

function getMailHeader() {
  var promise = $q(function(resolve, reject) {
    // Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync(callback);
    outlookService.getCallbackTokenAsync(function(asyncResult, userContext) {
      if (asyncResult.status == "succeeded") {
        $http({
          method: "POST",
          url: serverUrl + "/api/exchange/getMailHeader",
          data: JSON.stringify({
            authenticationToken: asyncResult.value,
            ewsUrl: outlookService.ewsUrl, // Office.context.mailbox.ewsUrl
            itemId: outlookService.itemId // Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId
          })
        }).then(resolve, reject);
      } else {
        reject("ERROR");
      }
    });
  });
  return promise;
}
```